# How to create unique ID and name created in a loop within Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a razor view, with a table of a simple shopping list.  In the first column of the table there is a dropdown list in each row.

Here is the code I am using to bring back each dropdown list

```
@foreach (var food in shoppingList.Foods)
{   
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(m => food , new SelectList(Model.Foods,"FoodID","Name",@food.FoodID))</td>
        <td>@food.Name</td>
        <td>@food.Price</td>
    </tr>
}
```

With this code I get the data as I need it, but I would like to provide a unique ID/name to each select. At the moment, this is the generated html.

FIRST SELECT

```
<td><select id="food" name="food">
<option selected="selected" value="1">Chicken</option>
<option value="2">Milk</option>
<option value="3">Bread</option>
<option value="4">Apple</option>
<option value="5">Cake</option>
<option value="6">Ham</option>
</select></td>
```

SECOND SELECT

```
<td><select id="food" name="food">
<option value="1">Chicken</option>
<option selected="selected" value="2">Milk</option>
<option value="3">Bread</option>
<option value="4">Apple</option>
<option value="5">Cake</option>
<option value="6">Ham</option>
</select></td>
```

Notice they both have id="food" name="food".

How I can give these unique id's and names?

Comment: Use the overloaded method? `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => food , new SelectList(Model.Foods,"FoodID","Name",@food.FoodID), new {@id="test", @name="lala"})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how you are thinking about binding this back to your model, but here is are couple ways you can do it:

1.

```
@{
    int i = 0;
}
@foreach (var food in shoppingList.Foods)
{
    @Html.DropDownList("food-" + i.ToString() , new SelectList(Model.Foods,"FoodID","Name",@food.FoodID))
    i++
}
```

2.

```
@{
    int i = 0;
}
@foreach (var food in shoppingList.Foods)
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => food , new SelectList(Model.Foods,"FoodID","Name",@food.FoodID), new { @id = "food-" + i.ToString() })
    i++
}
```

Comment: I dont think you need foreach loop if you are passing Model to the DropDownListFor helper.

Comment: I think you should consider using FOR loop. It will look simplier.

Comment: You can not pass @food.FoodID to C# method, you need to remove @ symbol.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you very much!!!  I've not really thought about how I'm going to save this back yet!